# Why does the project initialized with Remix's Indie stack get the error Hydration failed in Devtools?

Tags: reactjs, remix.run, hydration

When I was learning Remix, I followed the tutorial to initialize a project, but when I opened Devtools, I saw several errors reported on the console.
`Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <html>.`
`Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`*n
The most ridiculous thing is that I opened the index page of [Remix](https://remix.run) and its home page reported the same error, so I was especially curious about whether the hydration was successful and why this error happened

Answer (score 4):

This is a [well known React issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24430) caused by browser extensions modifying the DOM.

[It's more pronounced in Remix](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/4902) because it hydrates the entire `<html />`, not just a `<div id="root" />`.

You can confirm whether it's caused by a browser extension by testing with a browser profile which has no extensions installed (or incognito mode).

Kiliman has a workaround demonstrated here https://github.com/kiliman/remix-hydration-fix which involves rendering the head and the app separately.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I don't have these errors when I visit these pages without the extension, your suggestion is valid, it is indeed due to the modification of the extension that causes the errors